# Realm: what happens if we update primary key of a realm object?

Tags: realm

I just started using realm and I created a standalone object then I am setting unique id for that object and copying it into realm.

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int  id;
    private String          name;
}

User user = new User();
user.setName("some name");
user.setId(somePrimaryKey);
realm.copyToRealm(user);
```

Later I am updating primary key(id) of the same object

```
user.setId(newPrimaryKey);
```

and I observed this is causing duplication in realm. I just want to know is it normal in realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source code, the `user` actually is still standalone object after calling `realm.copyToRealm(user)`.

You should give the return value to user like `user = realm.copyToRealm(user);`, then the user will be managed by Realm.

After the user is managed by Realm, when you call `user.setId(newPrimaryKey);` and if the object with `newPrimaryKey` exists in the Realm, a `RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException` will be thrown.